# ler dados de uma url e fazer download

Tags: javascript, node.js

olá, preciso fazer o download de varias urls, executo o código abaixo dentro de um for, mas só funciona para o último url.

```
var anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.href = 'http://e-gov.betha.com.br/e-nota/teste';
anchor.download = 'http://e-gov.betha.com.br/e-nota/teste';
document.body.appendChild(anchor);
anchor.click();
```

Alguém tem alguma outra sugestão? Agradeço

Comment: Você vai executar isso no browser ou node?

Comment: no browser, mas caso não seja possível, executo no servidor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer download de um arquivo utilizando o `Node.js` você pode usar um módulo de requisição `http` e utilizar o `stream` de resposta para gerar um arquivo. No meu exemplo utilizarei o módulo [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request). Para instalá-lo utilize o comando:

```
npm i request
```

A seguinte função irá realizar o `download` do arquivo de uma `URL` para a pasta de destino:

```
const { createWriteStream } = require('fs');
const request = require('request');

const baixar = (url) => {
  return new Promise((resolver) => {
    const partes = url.split('/');
    const arquivo = createWriteStream(partes[partes.length - 1]);

    request(url).on('response', (resposta) => {
      const stream = resposta.pipe(arquivo);

      stream.on('finish', resolver);
    });
  });
};
```

Para realizar o download de vários arquivos você pode criar uma função que divida um `array` em segmentos menores para realizar em paralelo e executar a chamada dentro de um laço de repetição:

```
const dividir = (origem, tamanho) => {
  const segmentos = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < origem.length; i += tamanho) {
    segmentos.push(origem.slice(i, i + tamanho));
  }

  return segmentos;
};

(async () => {
  const links = [
    "http://localhost/arquivos/arquivo1.png",
    "http://localhost/arquivos/arquivo2.png",
    "http://localhost/arquivos/arquivo3.png",
    "http://localhost/arquivos/arquivo4.png",
    "http://localhost/arquivos/arquivo5.png",
    "http://localhost/arquivos/arquivo6.png",
    "http://localhost/arquivos/arquivo7.png",
    "http://localhost/arquivos/arquivo8.png",
  ];

  const partes = dividir(links, 3);

  for (parte of partes) {
    const promessas = parte.map(link => baixar(link));

    await Promise.all(promessas);
  }
})();
```